# Is every normal space metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

It is well known that every metric space is normal. But how do we know that normal topological spaces are metrizable?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157906/normal-non-metrizable-spaces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normal, Non-Metrizable Spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157906/normal-non-metrizable-spaces)